# Программа решения неопределенного интеграла

Tags: математика, .net, java

Нужно написать программу, которая решает неопределенный интеграл.

Подскажите, может, есть библиотека или готовое решение, где это реализовано?

Comment: @gsolovey, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @AlexeyM Ну, для учебного задания это  несколько крутовато. 

@gsolovey смотрите системы символьной математики. Возможно, они предоставляют интерфейс для пользовательских программ.